# How to find the correct child to search in a 2-3 Tree java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am working on a problem on BST and 2-3 Trees. The program does the same thing just with different data structures which is simulating the inventory of a hardware store.

Here I have a `correctChild` method and it is passed a `searchKey` which is a `string`, its task is to return a pointer to the child of `this` to which we should move in the search for `searchKey`.

I am trying to implement my 2-3 three on my .txt files but my pointer keeps giving me a null value which affects the insertion of data in my whole program.

```
/**********************************************************************************
 ***********************************************************************************
 *
 *  TwoThreeTree class
 *
 *  A leaf-based 2-3 tree:
 *    - all data is stored in the leaves
 *    - interior nodes contain only index values to guide searches
 *
 ***********************************************************************************
 ***********************************************************************************/

class TwoThreeTree
{
/**************************************************************
 **************************************************************
 * Nodes for the TwoThreeTree
 **************************************************************
 **************************************************************/

private class TwoThreeNode
{

    public String[] key;
    public ProductRecord data;
    public TwoThreeNode[] child;
    public int numKeys;
    public TwoThreeNode parent;

    // Create a new leaf for data d with key k. The leaf should have parent p.
    public TwoThreeNode( String k, ProductRecord d, TwoThreeNode p )
    {
        key = new String[1]; // A leaf holds only ONE key, with its associated data.
        key[0] = k; // The key of a data item!
        data = d; // The data item associated with this key.
        numKeys = 1;
        child = null; // A leaf will _never_ have children.
        parent = p;
    }

    // Create a new interior Node to contain index key k with parent p
    // and two children l and r.
    public TwoThreeNode( String k, TwoThreeNode p, TwoThreeNode l, TwoThreeNode r )
    {
        key = new String[2]; // May later hold 2 index values.
        key[0] = k; // The index value.
        key[1] = null;
        data = null; // Interior nodes never contain real data (only index keys to guide the search).
        numKeys = 1;
        child = new TwoThreeNode[3]; // May later have 3 children.
        child[0] = l;
        child[1] = r;
        child[2] = null;
        parent = p;
    }

    /************************************************************
     *
     *  printInorder
     *    Do an inorder traversal of the subtree rooted at
     *    the calling TwoThreeNode, printing the data values
     *    (i.e., only the data stored in the leaves)
     *
     **************************************************************/
    public void printInorder( )
    {
        ProductRecord code;

        if ( root.isLeaf() )
        {
            code = root.data;
            System.out.println(code);
        }
        else
        {
            root.child[0].printInorder();

            if (root.numKeys == 2)
            {
                root.child[1].printInorder();
            }
            root.child[2].printInorder();
        }

        /*************** YOUR CODE GOES HERE ***********************/

    } // end printInorder

    /************************************************************
     *
     * correctChild
     *
     * Figure out which child to move to in the search for searchKey.
     * Return a pointer to that child.
     *
     *  Idea:
     *  - i is the index of the child we think we should move to
     *  - start by assuming we should move to the rightmost child
     *  - loop: if searchKey is less than the index value separating
     *    the current child from the child immediately to the left of it
     *    move i to the child immediately to the left
     *
     **************************************************************/
    public TwoThreeNode correctChild( String searchKey )
    {
        TwoThreeNode result = null;

        int i = numKeys+1;


        if ( root!=null )
        {
            if ( !root.isLeaf() )
            {
                if ( this.numKeys == 1)  // three child nodes
                {
                    if ( searchKey.compareTo(this.key[0]) < 0 )
                    {
                        result = root.child[0];
                    }
                    else //greater than 0 move right
                    {
                        result = root.child[1];
                    }
                }

                if(root.numKeys ==2) // two child node
                {
                    if ( searchKey.compareTo(this.key[0]) < 0 )
                    {
                        result  = root.child[0];
                    }
                    else if( searchKey.compareTo(this.key[0]) > 0) //greater than the first key, move right
                    {
                        result = root.child[2];
                    }
                    else // the the middle child is less than or equal to the first key
                    {
                        result = root.child[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }














        return  result;
        /*************** YOUR CODE GOES HERE ***********************/
    }

    /************************************************************
     *
     *  isLeaf
     *    Return true if the TwoThreeNode is a leaf; false
     *    otherwise.
     *
     *    Note: A TwoThreeNode is a leaf if it has no children
     *    and if it has no children, then child is null.
     *
     **************************************************************/
    public boolean isLeaf()
    {
        return (child == null);
    }


} // end class TwoThreeNode

/***************************************************************
 ****************************************************************
 * Returning to class TwoThreeTree
 ****************************************************************
 ***************************************************************/

private TwoThreeNode root;


/************************************************************
 *
 * TwoThreeTree constructor
 *
 * Create an empty tree
 *
 **************************************************************/
public TwoThreeTree()
{
    root = null;
}


/************************************************************
 *
 * findLeaf
 *
 * Return the leaf where searchKey should be
 * (if it is in the tree at all).
 *
 * (A private helper method for search and insert.
 *
 **************************************************************/
private TwoThreeNode findLeaf( String searchKey )
{
    TwoThreeNode Lsearch = null;
    //ProductRecord code = null;

    if ( root!=null )
    {
        while ( !root.isLeaf() )
        {
            root.correctChild(searchKey);

        }
    }






    /*if ( root !=null )
    {


        result = find(searchKey);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("nooooo");
    }*/



    /*if ( root == null )
    {
        System.out.println("nooooo");
    }
    else
    {
        result = find(searchKey);

        System.out.println(result);
    }*/
    //res = find(searchKey);


    return Lsearch;


    /*************** YOUR CODE GOES HERE ***********************/

}


/************************************************************
 *
 * find
 *    Find and return the ProductRecord stored with key
 *    searchKey (or return null if searchKey is not in
 *    any leaf in the tree).
 *
 **************************************************************/

public ProductRecord find( String searchKey )
{

    TwoThreeNode result;
    ProductRecord code = null;


    if ( root!=null )
    {
        result = findLeaf(searchKey);

        if ( result!=null )
        {
            code = root.data;
        }

    }

    return code;

    /*************** YOUR CODE GOES HERE ***********************/

}


/************************************************************
 *
 * insert
 *    Insert ProductRecord p with key newKey into the tree.
 *     - First, search for newKey all the way to the leaves.
 *     - If the leaf contains newKey, simply return.
 *     - Otherwise, call recursive method addNewLeaf to handle
 *       the insertion (including any splitting and
 *       pushing up required).
 *
 **************************************************************/

public void insert( String newKey, ProductRecord p  )
{
    TwoThreeNode curr;
    TwoThreeNode nextCurr;
    boolean found = false;
    int i;

    if ( root == null )
    {
        // Empty tree: Add first node as the root (it has no parent)

        root = new TwoThreeNode( newKey, p, null );
    }
    else
    {
        // Tree is not empty.
        // Find the leaf that would contain newKey if newKey is already in the tree.

        curr = findLeaf( newKey );

        if ( curr != null && !curr.key[0].equals( newKey ) )
        {
            // The leaf at which the search ended does not contain searchKey.
            // Insert!

            addNewLeaf( newKey, p, curr );
        }
        else if ( curr == null )
        {
            System.out.println( "Not inserting " + newKey
                    + ": search failed with curr == null in non-empty tree" );
        }


    } // end else root != null

} // end insert



/************************************************************
 *
 * addNewLeaf
 *    Add a new leaf containing newKey and ProductRecord p into the tree.
 *    Add the new leaf as a child of the parent of leaf lsearch
 *    (where the search for newKey ended) if there's room.
 *    Otherwise, if the parent of lsearch has no room,
 *    split the parent and push the problem up to the grandparent.
 *    All work at the grandparent or above (where all nodes ---
 *    parent or child --- are interior nodes) is handled by
 *    helper method addIndexValueAndChild.
 *
 **************************************************************/
private void addNewLeaf( String newKey, ProductRecord p, TwoThreeNode lsearch )
{
    TwoThreeNode lsParent = lsearch.parent;
    TwoThreeNode newChild = new TwoThreeNode( newKey, p, lsParent );
    int lsIndex = -1; // (will be) index of pointer to lsearch in lsParent.child array
    // in case we have to split lsParent:
    TwoThreeNode newParent;
    String middleValue, largestValue;
    TwoThreeNode secondLargestChild, largestChild;

    if ( lsParent == null )
    {
        // lsearch is the ONLY node in the tree (it's the root)
        // create a new root to be the parent of lsearch and newChild
        if ( newKey.compareTo( lsearch.key[0] ) < 0 )
        {
            // newChild should be the left child, lsearch the right
            root = new TwoThreeNode( lsearch.key[0], null, newChild, lsearch );
        }
        else
        {
            root = new TwoThreeNode( newKey, null, lsearch, newChild );
        }
        lsearch.parent = root;
        newChild.parent = root;
    }
    else  // lsearch has a parent (and lsearch is not the root)
    {
        if ( lsearch == lsParent.child[0] )
            lsIndex = 0;
        else if ( lsearch == lsParent.child[1] )
            lsIndex = 1;
        else if ( lsParent.numKeys == 2 && lsearch == lsParent.child[2] )
            lsIndex = 2;
        else
            System.out.println( "ERROR in addNewLeaf: Leaf lsearch containing " + lsearch.key[0]
                    + " is not a child of its parent" );

        if ( lsParent.numKeys == 1 )
        {
            // Parent has room for another leaf child
            if ( newKey.compareTo( lsearch.key[0] ) < 0 )
            {
                if ( lsIndex == 1 )
                {
                    lsParent.child[2] = lsearch;
                    lsParent.child[1] = newChild;
                    lsParent.key[1] = lsearch.key[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    lsParent.child[2] = lsParent.child[1];
                    lsParent.key[1] = lsParent.key[0];
                    lsParent.child[1] = lsearch;
                    lsParent.child[0] = newChild;
                    lsParent.key[0] = lsearch.key[0];
                }
            }
            else // lsearch's key is < newKey
            {
                if ( lsIndex == 1 )
                {
                    lsParent.child[2] = newChild;
                    lsParent.key[1] = newKey;
                }
                else
                {
                    lsParent.child[2] = lsParent.child[1];
                    lsParent.key[1] = lsParent.key[0];
                    lsParent.child[1] = newChild;
                    lsParent.key[0] = newKey;
                }
            }
            lsParent.numKeys = 2;
            newChild.parent = lsParent;
        }
        else
        {
            // Parent has NO room for another leaf child --- split and push up
            if ( lsIndex == 2 )   // lsearch is rightmost of 3 children
            {
                if ( lsearch.key[0].compareTo( newKey ) < 0 )
                {
                    largestChild = newChild;
                    secondLargestChild = lsearch;
                    largestValue = newKey;
                    middleValue = lsParent.key[1];
                }
                else // newKey < lsearch.key[0]
                {
                    largestChild = lsearch;
                    secondLargestChild = newChild;
                    largestValue = lsearch.key[0];
                    middleValue = lsParent.key[1];
                }
            }
            else if ( lsIndex == 1 ) // lsearch is middle of 3 children
            {
                largestChild = lsParent.child[2];
                largestValue = lsParent.key[1];
                if ( lsearch.key[0].compareTo( newKey ) < 0 )
                {
                    secondLargestChild = newChild;
                    middleValue = newKey;
                }
                else // newKey < lsearch.key[0]
                {
                    secondLargestChild = lsearch;
                    middleValue = lsearch.key[0];
                    lsParent.child[1] = newChild;
                    newChild.parent = lsParent;
                }
            }
            else // lsIndex == 0   lsearch is leftmost of 3 children
            {
                largestChild = lsParent.child[2];
                secondLargestChild = lsParent.child[1];
                largestValue = lsParent.key[1];
                middleValue = lsParent.key[0];
                if ( lsearch.key[0].compareTo( newKey ) < 0 )
                {
                    lsParent.child[1] = newChild;
                    lsParent.key[0] = newKey;
                }
                else // newKey < lsearch.key[0]
                {
                    lsParent.child[1] = lsearch;
                    lsParent.child[0] = newChild;
                    lsParent.key[0] = lsearch.key[0];
                }
                newChild.parent = lsParent;
            }
            newParent = new TwoThreeNode( largestValue, lsParent.parent, secondLargestChild, largestChild );
            lsParent.numKeys = 1;
            lsParent.key[1] = null;
            lsParent.child[2] = null;
            largestChild.parent = newParent;
            secondLargestChild.parent = newParent;
            // add new parent to grandparent:
            if ( lsParent.parent == null )
            {
                root = new TwoThreeNode( middleValue, null, lsParent, newParent );
                lsParent.parent = root;
                newParent.parent = root;
            }
            else
                addIndexValueAndChild( lsParent.parent, middleValue, newParent );
        }
    } // end else lsearch has a parent
}


/************************************************************
 *
 *  addIndexValueAndChild
 *    Insert index value m and the corresponding new child (mChild)
 *  into TwoThreeNode curr.
 *
 *  (A child of curr was split, and index value m and new child mChild
 *  are the result of the split and must be added to curr, if possible.
 *  If they can't be added to curr (because curr is already full), then
 *  curr must also be split and the problem pushed up to curr's parent.)
 *
 **************************************************************/
private void addIndexValueAndChild( TwoThreeNode curr,
                                    String m, TwoThreeNode mChild )
{
    TwoThreeNode newNode;
    String midKey;

    if ( curr.numKeys == 1 )
    {
        // There's room for m and its child in curr.

        if ( m.compareTo( curr.key[0] ) < 0 )
        {
            // First child of curr was split to create mChild.
            // Order of keys: m < curr.key[0].
            // Order of children: curr.child[0] < mChild < curr.child[1].
            // m becomes the first key and its child becomes
            // the middle child.

            curr.key[1] = curr.key[0];
            curr.child[2] = curr.child[1];
            curr.key[0] = m;
            curr.child[1] = mChild;
        }
        else
        {
            // Second child of curr was split to create mChild.
            // Order of keys: curr.key[0] < m.
            // Order of children: curr.child[0] < curr.child[1] < mChild.
            // m becomes the second key and its child
            // becomes the rightmost child.

            curr.key[1] = m;
            curr.child[2] = mChild;
        }
        curr.numKeys = 2;
        mChild.parent = curr;
    }
    else
    {
        // There's no room for m and its child in curr.
        // Split curr into two (the original
        // TwoThreeNode curr and a new TwoThreeNode) and
        // push the middle key and a pointer to the new
        // TwoThreeNode up to the parent.

        if ( m.compareTo( curr.key[0] ) < 0 )
        {
            // First child of curr was split to create mChild.
            // Order of keys: m < curr.key[0] < curr.key[1].
            // Order of children:
            // curr.child[0] < mChild < curr.child[1] < curr.child[2].
            // Original node gets key m and children
            // curr.child[0] and mChild.
            // New node gets key curr.key[1] and children
            // curr.child[1] and curr.child[2].
            // curr.key[0] is the middle key.

            midKey = curr.key[0];
            newNode = new TwoThreeNode( curr.key[1], curr.parent, curr.child[1], curr.child[2] );
            curr.child[1].parent = newNode;
            curr.child[2].parent = newNode;
            mChild.parent = curr;
            curr.key[0] = m;
            curr.child[1] = mChild;
        }
        else if ( m.compareTo( curr.key[1] ) < 0 )
        {
            // Second child of curr was split to create curr.
            // Order of keys: curr.key[0] < m < curr.key[1].
            // Order of children:
            // curr.child[0] < curr.child[1] < mChild < curr.child[2].
            // Original node retains key curr.key[0] and children
            // curr.child[0] and curr.child[1].
            // New node gets key curr.key[1] and children
            // mChild and curr.child[2].
            // m is  the middle key.

            midKey = m;
            newNode = new TwoThreeNode( curr.key[1], curr.parent, mChild, curr.child[2] );
            mChild.parent = newNode;
            curr.child[2].parent = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            // Order of keys: curr.key[0] < curr.key[1] < m.
            // Order of children:
            // curr.child[0] < curr.child[1] < curr.child[2] < mChild.
            // Original node retains key curr.key[0] and children
            // curr.child[0] and curr.child[1].
            // New node gets key m and children
            // curr.child[2] and mChild.
            // curr.key[1] is the middle key.

            midKey = curr.key[1];
            newNode = new TwoThreeNode( m, curr.parent, curr.child[2], mChild );
            curr.child[2].parent = newNode;
            mChild.parent = newNode;
        }
        curr.numKeys = 1;
        curr.key[1] = null;
        curr.child[2] = null;
        if ( curr != root )
            addIndexValueAndChild( curr.parent, midKey, newNode );
        else
        {
            root = new TwoThreeNode( midKey, null, curr, newNode );
            curr.parent = root;
            newNode.parent = root;
        }
    }
} // end addIndexValueAndChild


/************************************************************
 *
 *  printTable
 *    Print an appropriate message if the tree is empty;
 *    otherwise, call a recursive method to print the
 *    data values in an inorder traversal.
 *
 **************************************************************/
public void printTable()
{

    if ( root != null )
    {

        this.root.printInorder();

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The tree is empty");
    }

    /*************** YOUR CODE GOES HERE ***********************/

} // end printTree

} // end class TwoThreeTree
```

It affects my insert method

```
public void insert( String newKey, ProductRecord p  )
    {
        TwoThreeNode curr;
        TwoThreeNode nextCurr;
        boolean found = false;
        int i;

        if ( root == null )
        {
            // Empty tree: Add first node as the root (it has no parent)

            root = new TwoThreeNode( newKey, p, null );
        }
        else
        {
            // Tree is not empty.
            // Find the leaf that would contain newKey if newKey is already in the tree.

            curr = findLeaf( newKey );

            if ( curr != null && !curr.key[0].equals( newKey ) )
            {
                // The leaf at which the search ended does not contain searchKey.
                // Insert!

                addNewLeaf( newKey, p, curr );
            }
            else if ( curr == null )
            {
                System.out.println( "Not inserting " + newKey
                        + ": search failed with curr == null in non-empty tree" );
            }


        } // end else root != null

    } // end insert
```

and makes my output print this instead of adding and that's because of findLeaf

```
Not inserting P24-Qbw-2495: search failed with curr == null in non-empty tree
Not inserting P33-Qes-4782: search failed with curr == null in non-empty tree
Not inserting P25-Taa-1244: search failed with curr == null in non-empty tree
Not inserting P25-Tab-3509: search failed with curr == null in non-empty tree
Not inserting P25-Tab-3506: search failed with curr == null in non-empty tree
Not inserting P25-Tac-3672: search failed with curr == null in non-empty tree
```

What is the best way to check for the correct child of a key for a 2-3 tree? any references or suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks

The findLeaf method uses correct child

```
private TwoThreeNode findLeaf( String searchKey )
{
    TwoThreeNode Lsearch = null;
    //ProductRecord code = null;

    if ( root!=null )
    {
        while ( !root.isLeaf() )
        {
            root.correctChild(searchKey);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `findLeaf` method is basically doing nothing as `Lsearch` is never assigned a value and so it will always return `null`.

This is what it looks like without all the commented code:

```
private TwoThreeNode findLeaf(String searchKey) {
  TwoThreeNode Lsearch = null;

  if ( root!=null ) {
    while (!root.isLeaf()) {
      root.correctChild(searchKey);
    }
  }

  return Lsearch;
}
```

Presumably, to fix the problem (or at least progress further) you need to do an assignment such as `Lsearch = root.correctChild(searchKey)`.